# How to pass text value after sending in another component?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I create two step register page. In first step get data from user like name , last name , phone number. I need to pass value of phone number to last step to check verify code is correct or not.
How to pass phone number after submit to last step state?
This is my first step code :

```
    class RegisterMain extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {

                firstName: "",
                lastName: "",
                phoneNumber: "",
                state: "",
                city: "",
                address: ""

        }
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)

    }

    static propTypes = {
        isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool,
        register: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    }

    onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const {
            firstName,
            lastName,
            phoneNumber,
            address,
            state,
            city
        } = this.state;
        const newUser = {
            firstName,
            lastName,
            phoneNumber,
            address,
            state,
            city
        };
        this.props.register(newUser);
        console.log(newUser)
    }
    onChange(event) {
        const value = event.target.value;
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: value
        })
    }
 
    render() {

        return (
            <div className="register-form-box">
              
                <form className="login-form pt-2 float-right" onSubmit={this.onSubmit} >
                    <Row>
                        <div className={"col-12 col-lg-6"}>

                            <input type={"text"}
                                   placeholder={"Last Name"}
                                   name={"lastName"}
                                   onChange={this.onChange}
                                   autoComplete="on"
                                   value={this.state.lastName}
                                   onBlur={(e) => e.target.placeholder = "Last Name"}
                                   onFocus={(e) => e.target.placeholder = ""}
                                   className={" info-login-input"}/>
                        </div>
                        <div className={"col-12 col-lg-6"}>
                            <input
                                name={"firstName"}
                                type={"text"}
                                placeholder={"First Name"}
                                onChange={this.onChange}
                                autoComplete="on"
                                value={this.state.firstName}
                                onBlur={(e) => e.target.placeholder = "First Name"}
                                onFocus={(e) => e.target.placeholder = ""}
                                className={"info-login-input"}/>
                        </div>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <div className="col-12">
                            <input type={"text"}
                                   placeholder={"Phone"}
                                   name={"phoneNumber"}
                                   onChange={this.onChange}
                                   autoComplete="on"
                                   value={this.state.phoneNumber}
                                   onBlur={(e) => e.target.placeholder = "Phone"}
                                   onFocus={(e) => e.target.placeholder = ""}
                                   className={" mt-3 info-login-input"}/>
                        </div>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <div className="col-lg-6 col-12 ">

                            <input type={"text"}
                                   placeholder={"City"}
                                   name={"city"}
                                   onChange={this.onChange}
                                   autoComplete="on"
                                   value={this.state.city}
                                   onBlur={(e) => e.target.placeholder = "City"}
                                   onFocus={(e) => e.target.placeholder = ""}
                                   className={"block mt-3 info-login-input"}/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-lg-6 col-12">
                            <input type={"text"}
                                   placeholder={"Province"}
                                   name={"state"}
                                   onChange={this.onChange}
                                   autoComplete="on"
                                   value={this.state.state}
                                   onBlur={(e) => e.target.placeholder = "Province"}
                                   onFocus={(e) => e.target.placeholder = ""}
                                   className={"block mt-3 info-login-input"}/>
                        </div>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <div className={"col-12 mt-3"}>
                                <textarea name={"address"}
                                          value={this.state.address}
                                          onChange={this.onChange}
                                          autoComplete={"on"}
                                          placeholder={"address"}
                                          onBlur={(e) => e.target.placeholder = "address"}
                                          onFocus={(e) => e.target.placeholder = ""}/>
                        </div>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <div className={"col-12 d-none"}>
                            <input

                                name={"identityType"}
                                type={"text"}
                                onChange={this.onChange}
                                value={this.state.identityType}
                                className={"info-login-input"}/>
                        </div>
                    </Row>
                 
                    <div className="row justify-content-center my-3 ">
                        <div className="col-12 mx-auto send-register-btn">
                            <button type="submit" >SignUp</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isAuthenticated: state.isAuthenticated,
    error: state.error,
    user : state.auth,

})
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {register})(RegisterMain);
```

And this my last step code :

```
 class CheckCodeMain extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            phoneNumber: ""
        }
    }
    handleParentData = (formModel) => {
        console.log(formModel);
        this.setState({ ...formModel })
    }
  

    state = {
        verificationCode: "",
        msg: null
    }
    static propTypes = {
        isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool,
        error: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        verifyCode: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        register: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        clearError: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    };



    onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const {verificationCode} = this.state;
        const user = {
            verificationCode
        };
        this.props.verificationCode(user);
        console.log(verifyCode)

    }
    handleChange = verificationCode => this.setState({verificationCode});

    render() {
     
        return (

            <div className="register-form-box check-code-wrapper">
                <div className="register-title-box">
                    <h3>
Check Code
                    </h3>
                   
                </div>
                <div className={"otp-code-verif-inputs"}>
                    <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                        <OtpInput
                            value={this.state.verificationCode}
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                            numInputs={5}
                        />
                        <input
                        value={this.state.phoneNumber}
                        />
                        <div className={"approve-btn-check"}>
                            <button onSubmit={this.onSubmit} className={"otp-code-next-step"}> Submit
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                </div>
     
            </div>

        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isAuthenticated: state.isAuthenticated,
    verifyCode: state.verifyCode,
    error: state.error,
    register : state.register,
    auth: state.auth,
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
    verifyCode, clearError, loadUser, register
})(CheckCodeMain);
```

And this my register action, I use redux for this project :

```
    export const register = ({
                             firstName,
                             lastName,
                             phoneNumber,
                             address,
                             state,
                             identityType,
                             city

                         }) => (dispatch) => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
    };
    const body = JSON.stringify({
        firstName,
        lastName,
        phoneNumber,
        address,
        identityType,
        state,
        city
    });
    axios.post("/users/register",  body, config).then(
        (res) =>
            dispatch({
                type: REGISTER_SUCCESS,
                payload: res.data,
            }),

    ) .then(
            () => {
                history.push({
                    pathname: '/check-code',
                   state
                })
            }
        ).catch((err) => {
        dispatch(
            returnError(err.response, err.res)
        );
        dispatch({
            type: REGISTER_FAIL
        });
    });
}
```

This is my routing component and set store to my Provider :

```
    import {createBrowserHistory} from "history";


export const history = createBrowserHistory();

const AppRouter = (props) => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
            <Router history={history} >
                <Navigation/>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" exact component={() => <Home/>}/>
                    <Route path={"/login-preview"} exact component={() => <LoginPreview/>}/>
                    <Route path={"/profile"} exact component={() => <Profile/>}/>
                    <Route path={"/register"} exact component={() => <Register />}/>
                    <Route path={"/check-code"}   component={() => <CheckCode />}/>
                    <Route path={"/login"} exact component={() => <Login/>}/>
                </Switch>
                <Footer/>
            </Router>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
);

export default AppRouter;
```

I try to pass state with history.push but give nothing in last component. my react-router-dom version is 5.2.0 and my history version is 5.0.0.

Comment: Where are you doing a route transition between steps?

Comment: @DrewReese I update my question by my routing

Comment: I still don't see where you navigate from one step to the next and try to pass any state. Also, you ***definitely don't want to do*** `component={() => <Profile/>}` as this will remount the component each render, instead use `component={Profile}`.

Comment: @DrewReese I try to navigate between Register to Check Code by pass value of phone number

Comment: Ah, I see, you are navigating in the action. Sorry, I misunderstood your steps. It looks like you pass only the `state` field as route state instead of passing the `phoneNumber` field in route state on to the "/check-code" route. It should be `history.push({ pathname: '/check-code', state: { phoneNumber } })`, then on the next step access `this.props.location.state.phoneNumber`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common approach to that is to create a stateful component that renders both routes and keeps the shared state of the individual steps:

```
const InitialState = {
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    phoneNumber: "",
    state: "",
    city: "",
    address: ""
};

const Register = () => {
    const {path} = useRouteMatch();
    const [formState, setFormState] = useState(InitialState);
    const handleChange = useCallback(values => setFormState(values), []);

    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path={`${path}/form`}>
                <RegisterMain values={formState} onChange={handleChange} />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path={`${path}/confirm`}>
                <CheckCodeMain values={formState} onChange={handleChange} />
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    );
}
```

Inside of your individual steps you can then call the `onChange` handler to store the current values in the parent state and redirect to the next steps route.

The `Register` component could be rendered like that in your `AppRouter`:

```
<Route path="/register" component={Register} />
```

Comment: What's value of useState hook? initial State is not defined

Comment: @SajjadShiasi Well, I omited that for the sake of simplicity of the example but of course that would be the initial values of your registration form. I updated my answer.

Comment: @SajjadShiasi And of course you wouldn't have to keep the state in `RegisterMain` anymore. You would access it via the `values` prop and update it with the `onChange` prop.

Comment: Thank you, but now I have white blank page in register page and check code page

Comment: @SajjadShiasi Well this is just an example to show the general approach. Of course you have to refactor `RegisterMain` and `CheckCodeMain` to make it work. And you might also need to tweak the paths used to match your needs.

Comment: Thank You bro, I will trying to solve this problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235555/discussion-between-sajjad-shiasi-and-trixn).